# How to get lowest price from custom fields of child posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with the following custom_post_type parent-child structure:

```
Brand           (main parent post)
    Product     (child post of Brand, but parent post for versions) 
       Version  (child post of Product) 
       Version  (child post of Product) 
       Version  (child post of Product) 
       ...
```

Each version child-post has a `$price` post_meta field, with different values.

I'd like to display in the Product page level a text saying "From `$lowestPrice` to `$highestPrice`"

My question is:

How can I retrieve the lowest and highest values of `$price` among all the Version child-posts post_meta fields in order to get build the values for `$lowestPrice` and `$highestPrice`

I understand that a wp_query or something similar would work?

I hope I was clear :)

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards,

Chris.

Comment: Yep, [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is the way I would go in this case. Have a look at the documentation and if you get stuck somewhere update your question (and, preferably, include some code as well) and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this :)

```
$parent_id = $posts[0]->ID;
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'post_type' => 'fichas',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$properties_query = new WP_Query($args);
$prices = array();

if ($properties_query->have_posts()):
    while ($properties_query->have_posts()):
        $properties_query->the_post();
        $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'precio_oferta', true);
        if (isset($price) && !empty($price))
            {
            $prices[] = $price;
            }

    endwhile;
    $max_price = max($prices);
    $min_price = min($prices);
endif;

wp_reset_query();

echo $max_price; // displays the max price
echo $min_price; // displays the minumum price
```